# Is it possible to have a tuple contain only one tuple without the comma?

Tags: python, data-structures, tuples

Can I have a tuple that contains just one tuple (without any additional commas) like the following:

((0,1))

I know that if I do the following, this works (kind of):

```
final_tuple = ()
input_tuple = (0,1)
final_tuple = ((input_tuple,))

print(str(final_tuple))
```

Output: ((0,1),)

Comment: Well: `((0,1),)`…!?

Comment: FYI, the outer parentheses in `((input_tuple,))` do nothing. Just `(input_tuple,)` accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((0, 1),)` may be what you want.